# Migrate All Data of CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, migration

Old website is WordPress + CiviCRM. We are rebuilding the website, still in WordPress. I already installed CiviCRM in new WordPress website.

How to export all CiviCRM data from old website and import it to the new website.

Comment: Relocating all data from one CiviCRM instance to the other can be an involved and challenging process, depending on its size and complexity. Here are the general steps you can follow when migrating all your information: **Backup Your CiviCRM Database and Files:**
Before beginning the migration process, it's essential that you create a backup of your current CiviCRM database and files for safety measures in case something goes amiss during its transfer. This safeguard can protect both you and your organization in case anything unexpected arises during its journey. **Install CiviCRM on the Targe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page might help: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

I am assuming you are migrating to a new version of CiviCRM. What I would do:

1. upgrade CiviCRM on the old site to the version of the new site
2. dump the CiviCRM DB
3. restore the DB on the new CiviCRM site
4. Follow the steps in the guide in the link above